# nested ng-repeats and ng-ifs inside a select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html in my component template:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedLob">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <div ng-repeat="lob in vm.lobs track by lob.id">
        <option ng-if="lob.specialPrograms.length == 0" value="{{lob.id}}">
            {{lob.name}}
        </option>
        <optgroup ng-if="lob.specialPrograms.length > 0" label="{{lob.name}}">
            <option ng-repeat="sp in lob.specialPrograms track by sp.id" value="{{sp.id}}">
                {{sp.name}}
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </div>
</select>
```

**vm.lobs** - this is an array of lob objects

**lob** - this is a lob object with fields id, name, and specialPrograms where each field is of type string, string, array respectively.

**lob.specialPrograms** - an array of specialprograms objects

**sp** - a specialprogram object with fields id and name. Both fields are strings.

I am trying to populate a drop down when I click a button, so when this template is first ran through the `vm.lobs` array is empty. Then when I click the button an ajax call is fired and the `vm.lobs` array is populated.

As you can see, I want to create an option element or optgroup element with a list of option elements depending on if the lob has any values in its specialprograms array. The problem is that this isn't happening when the `vm.lobs` array is populated.

Here's the generated html from the above template:

```
<select class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="vm.selectedLob">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>

        <!-- ngIf: lob.specialPrograms.length == 0 -->
        <!-- ngIf: lob.specialPrograms.length > 0 -->

</select>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check if specialPrograms is an array object it may be `null` or `undefined`, if it is valid object check if this code is working when you change `select` to `div` some browsers may have troubles with generating `options` and `optgroups` - IMHO it is better to use custom dropdowns e.g. bootstrap dropdown from angular-strap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to go the directive route using jquery and a deferred promise from the ajax call. This was to maintain the order of the list. The solution that @Konkko posted is a good solution if I didn't need to maintain the order of the list.

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('lobOptionGroups', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.vm.deferLob.then(function(lobs){
                scope.vm.lobs = lobs;
                for(var i = 0; i < lobs.length; i++){
                    var lob = lobs[i];

                    if(lob.specialPrograms.length > 0){
                        var optGroup = $("<optgroup label='"+lob.name+"'></optgroup>");

                        for(var j = 0; j < lob.specialPrograms.length; j++){
                            var sp = lob.specialPrograms[j];
                            optGroup.append($("<option value='"+sp.id+"'>"+sp.name+"</option>"));
                        }

                        elem.append(optGroup);
                    }
                    else{
                        elem.append($("<option value='"+lob.id+"'>"+lob.name+"</option>"));
                    }
                }
            },
            function(error){

            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a filter something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedLob" ng-init="vm.selectedLob = 0">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="lob in lobs | filter: noSpecialPrograms" value="{{lob.id}}">
          {{lob.name}}
      </option>
      <optgroup ng-repeat="lob in lobs | filter: hasSpecialPrograms">
        <option ng-repeat="sp in lob.specialPrograms" value="{{lob.id + sp.id}}">
          {{sp.name}} {{lob.id + sp.id}}
        </option> 
      </optgroup>
  </select>
```

And js

```
$scope.noSpecialPrograms = function(item) {
    return item.specialPrograms.length === 0;
};

$scope.hasSpecialPrograms = function(item) {
    return item.specialPrograms.length > 0;
};
```

Comment: While this is a good solution, I need them in a particular order, I cant do all the lobs with no special programs first. They are intermingled with the lobs that have special programs. My solution is to write a directive and do it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not that you want but is more easy work whith  ng-options when are selects,even you can group the options example:

---

`<label>Color grouped by shade, with some disabled:
    <select ng-model="myColor"
          ng-options="color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors">
    </select>
</label>`

here is the documentation for ng-options: [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)